# p 129 of Gustav Radbruch's Einführung in Die Rechtswissenschaft

Tags: interpretation

My local library doesn't subscribe to [PhilPapers](https://philpapers.org/rec/RADEID). Anyone here have it pls? No library near me has this German book.

Robert Schütze. [*European Union Law* 2 ed 2018](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-9780198714927?cc=ca&lang=en&). [p. 211](https://books.google.com/books?id=LzNlDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA206&ots=B43pF3QgKD&dq=%22functionaries%20of%20the%20case%20law%22&pg=PA206#v=onepage&q&f=false). All emboldenings are mine. 
Pls see the tag line beside the red arrow

> In the beautifully paradoxical words of G. Radbruch: ‘The interpretation is the result of
>   **its** result.’ See G. Radbruch, *Einführung in die Rechtswissenschaft* (Meyer, 1925), 129.

1. What does "its" refer to it here?
2. I don't speak German like the author. Can someone explain these "beautifully paradoxical words like I'm 5?

> [image]

Comment: Already asked [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/43342/meaning-judicial-interpretation-is-the-result-of-its-result) (by yourself) and wrongfully auto-deleted by Community.

Comment: There are several copies on www.abebooks.com. I think the cheapest is about $25 (including shipping from Germany to USA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain these "beautifully paradoxical words like I'm 5?

Aside from [not] having access to the text by Radbruch, the reasonable conjecture is that the quote of Radbruch paraphrases what Schütze says in the main text: namely, that a judge's choice of "interpretative method" (historical, literal, systematic, or teleological) somewhat determines or helps to predict how he will decide a case.

> What does "its" refer to it here?

The emboldened "its" likely refers to the judge's *interpretative method*, although that is inconsequential since Schütze premises that quote with words that convey similarity with the expression "*[a] judicial preference for an interpretative method will thus prejudge the result of the interpretation*".